# User Input with decimals

Tags: html, angularjs

i want an < input> with decimals.

When a user entering for example 10 it should shows up 0.10 instead of 10 or 10.00.

Is this possible with HTML or do i need Angular/Javascript for this?

I also tried input type="numbers".. but this is same problem. This also add a comma, instead a point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Number Input - Always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891714/how-to-create-a-dollar-amount-input-field-in-an-html-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the jQuery Libary Mask (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991945/6331266).

```
<script src="/your/path/to/jquery-mask.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.usd_input').mask('00000.00', { reverse: true });
});
</script>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="usd_input" name="dollar_amt">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcte6b0g/

Answer (score 0):

Try  `<input type="number" step="0.01" />`

Comment: this is not working. user input for example 22 is then 22. Not 0.22.